# Passing commit message and author through to Cypress Cloud

Tags: github-actions, cypress

I have a workflow to run Cypress tests that is recording to Cypress Cloud and for some reason it's not passing over the commit message.

Right now I have the following:

```
name: Cypress Tests
on: [push, deployment_status]
jobs:
  cypress-run:
    if: github.event_name == 'deployment_status' && github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      COMMIT_INFO_MESSAGE: ${{ toJson(github.event.head_commit.message) }} (by ${{ toJson(github.event.head_commit.author) }})
      COMMIT_INFO_AUTHOR: ${{ toJson(github.event.head_commit.author) }}
    container: cypress/included:cypress-12.7.0-node-18.14.1-chrome-110.0.5481.96-1-ff-109.0-edge-110.0.1587.41-1
    steps:
      - name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6.6.0
        with:
          install-command: npm install
          start: npm run cypress:run:dev --verbose
          project: apps/game-zone-e2e
          browser: chrome
          record: true
          parallel: true
        env:
          # DEBUG: 'cypress:*'
          CYPRESS_PROJECT_ID: ${{ vars.CYPRESS_PROJECT_ID }}
          CYPRESS_BASE_URL: ${{ github.event.deployment_status.target_url }}
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
          NX_CLOUD_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NX_CLOUD_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          COMMIT_INFO_MESSAGE: ${{ env.COMMIT_INFO_MESSAGE }}
          COMMIT_INFO_AUTHOR: ${{ env.COMMIT_INFO_AUTHOR }}
```

I have echo'ed these out in the job level and I am getting the values out so i know the notation is correct but it's showing "null (by null)" for `COMMIT_INFO_MESSAGE`.

What am I doing wrong here? Whats even more strange to me is `github.event.deployment_status.target_url` is fine and working in that env var.

Comment: One reason might be that `deployment_status` event, unlike the `push` event, does not provide the `github.event.head_commit` parameter. Docs: https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#deployment_status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish there was a cleaner solution here, but never the less it works well. I had to use git commands in an additional step to extract the commit, author and other git info for cypress.

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout 
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Save Git values
    # pass env variables from this step to other steps
    # using GitHub Actions environment file
    # https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files
    run: |
      git config --global --add safe.directory "$GITHUB_WORKSPACE"
      echo COMMIT_INFO_BRANCH=$(git show-branch --no-name HEAD) >> $GITHUB_ENV
      echo COMMIT_INFO_MESSAGE=$(git show -s --format='%h %s') >> $GITHUB_ENV
      echo COMMIT_INFO_EMAIL=$(git show -s --pretty=%ae) >> $GITHUB_ENV
      echo COMMIT_INFO_AUTHOR=$(git show -s --pretty=%an) >> $GITHUB_ENV
      echo COMMIT_INFO_SHA=$(git show -s --pretty=%H) >> $GITHUB_ENV
      echo COMMIT_INFO_TIMESTAMP=$(git show -s --pretty=%ct) >> $GITHUB_ENV
      echo COMMIT_INFO_REMOTE=$(git config --get remote.origin.url) >> $GITHUB_ENV
      # delete the .git folder afterwords to use the environment values
      rm -rf .git
```